# Stuck at Cerulean gym in Pokemon Crystal

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I am playing Pokemon Crystal on an emulator (visual boy advance). I've made it to the Kanto region and got as far as Cerulean City and got stuck at the gym.

I went to the power plant and normally the manager says the generator is missing a part. In my game the manager say it's running fine and gives me a TM. I go back to the Cerulean Gym and there is no Team Rocket member waiting for me and the gym is empty. I can strangely pickup the machine parts that should have been needed for the power plant. **I believe my game events are messed up**.

Other evidence:

- The mimic girl in Saffron City who needs her pokedoll from Vermillion City isn't even asking for it and gave me the "Pass" for the magnet train right away
- Although I have the pass and the power plant has the power working the train won't work in Saffron City
- The president of the pokefan club in Vermillion won't tell me his long winded story
- Earlier on, I went to the bottom of the Mt. Mortar and couldn't fight the trainer that gives you a Tyrogue. He talks like we've fought already

My question(s) are:

- **Can I do something in game to proceed with the story?**
- **Is there a way to use a save editor to change game events?**
- **Can I use the emulator to somehow change my game's events?**

FYI: Misty is not at the end of route 25 north of the city. I sadly have no backup save.

Comment: Looks like either your save or your ROM is broken. If you get your hands on a save editor capable of explaining to you what to do, you can probably fix this. Otherwise, you'd need to reverse-engineer the code yourself or find resources online on how to do that. The emulator usually can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

you **must talk to all people in the power plant** or else the gym will be empty.